# R: Very basic example for averaging a Time Series

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, moving-average

I am qute new to R and studied several posts and websites about time series and moving averaging but simply cannot find a useful hint averging a special period of time.

My data is a table via readcsv with a date and time in one column and several other columns with values. The time steps in the data are not constant, so sometimes 5 minutes, sometimes 2 hours. Eg.

```
2014-01-25 14:50:00, 4, 8
2014-01-25 14:55:00, 3, 7
2014-01-25 15:00:00, 1, 4
2014-01-25 15:20:24, 12, 34
2014-01-25 17:19:00, 150, 225
2014-01-25 19:00:00, 300, 400
2014-01-25 21:00:00, NA, NA
2014-01-25 23:19:00, 312, 405
```

So I look for an averaging plot that

1. calculates data average in **arbitrary intervals** like 30 minutes, 1 hour, 1 day etc. So lower steps should be aggregated and higher steps should be disaggregated.
2. (removed, since it is trivial to get value per hour from a time series D which is averaged by X hours with D/x.)
3. data flagged as NA should not be taken into account. So the function should not interpolate/smooth through Na gaps and performing a line plot should not connect the points between a NA gap with a line.

I already tried

```
aggregate(list(value1=data$value1,value2=data$value2), list(time=cut(data$time, "1 hour")), sum)
```

but this does not fulfill needs 1 and 3 and is not able to disaggregate 2-hourly data steps.

Comment: can you put up a sample of your dataframe or a link to the data?

Comment: Can you define "value per hour" and explain how that's different from the mean?   As to point 3, most `R` functions have an `na.rm` or `na.omit` argument that removes `NA` from the calculation, but it's not clear what you mean by "not connect the points."

Comment: I tried to explain more in this edit. Performing a simple mean does not aggregate/disaggregate properly when time steps are not constant.

Comment: So when there is no answer from the R community I guess there is no solution for this?

Comment: Found two links, that might help you solve the problem: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-August/334180.html

And in general if you want a good link to start your journey with Time Series Analysis in R, this link might help: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/time-series-analysis-101-in-r-and-python-1e1a7f7c3e51

Please do let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Answering point 3:  `plot` automatically skips `NA` values and breaks the line.

Try this example:

```
plot(c(1:5,NA,NA,6:10),t='l')
```

Now, if you want to 'smooth' or average over time intervals purely for graphical purposes, It's probably easiest to start out by separating your data at each line with an `NA` and then doing a spline or other smoothing operation on each subsection separately.

Comment: Thanks, but since the data is a huge amount of lines with arbitrarily distributed NA lines, It is not practical to perform a section-wise averging by hand. But your example shows quite nicely that a line plot will not connect through NA gaps, so I think the problem is solved as soon as someone knows a solution for point 1.

Comment: rollmean documentation: "k: integer width of the rolling window". Since I have time steps of differing lengths, this does not seem to be the right thing. That's why I ask.